# Haskell wildcard symbol usage

Tags: haskell

In the source code for the Applicative instance for Maybe we have:

```
instance Applicative Maybe where
pure = Just

Just f  <*> m       = fmap f m
Nothing <*> _m      = Nothing

Just _m1 *> m2      = m2
Nothing  *> _m2     = Nothing
```

I had thought that '_' is used as a wildcard in patterns. What is the meaning here therefore of '_m' and '_m2' values? Is this a GHC coding convention? Is there some performance advantage to not using _?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that `_` is a wildcard.  What you see here are just variables with names beginning with `_`; there's no special syntax.  Both `_` and variables match any value, but `_` signals that you're ignoring that value.  Consequently, GHC will warn you if you define a variable and don't use it, which comes in handy.  But what if you want to document *what* you're ignoring, without being warned that you're ignoring it?  Well, `_` is just another word character in Haskell, so you can begin a variable name with it.  And GHC will assume that any `_`-initial variable names you defined are *intended* to be unused, and refrain from warning you about them.

Thus, in

```
Just f  <*> m  = fmap f m
Nothing <*> _m = Nothing
```

The `_m` is used to be clear that it's the same thing as the `m` above, but isn't being used.  If we replaced it with `_`, that might be less clear.  And if we replaced it with `m`, we'd get a warning:

```
…: warning: [-Wunused-matches]
    Defined but not used: ‘m’
```

---

In general, `_` is only a little bit special in Haskell pattern matches.  Besides the "no warnings" property above (which doesn't change what the program does, only the compiler messages), matching against `_` is almost exactly like matching against any other variable.  There are only two differences:

1. You can match against multiple `_`s at once.

   ```
   star1, star2 :: a -> b -> Char
   star1 _ _ = '*'
   star2 x y = '*'
   -- ILLEGAL:
   -- star3 x x = '*'
   ```

   Every `_` is distinct – two underscores are not the same thing as each other.  However, when we match against variables, all the variables we match against have to be distinct; you can't match against "x" twice.  (You can sort of think of `_` as a variable whose name is different each time.)
2. You can't use `_` in expressions, only in patterns.

   ```
   id2 :: a -> a
   -- ILLEGAL:
   -- id1 _ = _
   id2 x = x
   ```

   Because `_` doesn't "remember" what it matched against, as we saw above, you can never use it in an expression.  It's only ever a pattern.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use the `_` prefix, you will get warning when compiling:

```
gcc -Wall test.hs:

test.hs:21:18: Warning: Defined but not used: ‘m’

test.hs:23:11: Warning: Defined but not used: ‘m1’

test.hs:24:18: Warning: Defined but not used: ‘m2’
```

You can use `_` to avoid the warnings. So, `_var` is used to give a name to the variable and to avoid warning. You can do something like this:

```
Justa m1 *> _m      = _m
```

But with wildcards, you cannot do something like this:

```
Just m1 *> _ = _
```

Comment: But the underscore variable is not being used on the RHS?

Comment: @andro In your specific example, it doesn't matter. And using `_` is equivalent to `_var`. But in general, they differ.